# OutOfMemoryException when reading large VideoFile to ByteArray

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, video

So after searching Stackoverflow for hours I tried loads of methods and library's but not ONE of them was the answer to my problem.

The problem is as follows:

```
val videoPath = getVideoPathFromURI(getSelectedVideoUri(requestCode, data))
val videoBytes = FileInputStream(File(videoPath)).use { input ->
    input.readBytes()
}
```

This part is what I've had in my code before I found out about the bug.

Two of the many methods I tried are as follows:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun InputStream.readAllBytes(): ByteArray {
    val bufLen = 4 * 0x400 // 4KB
    val buf = ByteArray(bufLen)
    var readLen: Int = 0

    ByteArrayOutputStream().use { o ->
        this.use { i ->
            while (i.read(buf, 0, bufLen).also { readLen = it } != -1)
                o.write(buf, 0, readLen)
        }

        return o.toByteArray()
    }
}

private fun getByteArray(videoPath: String): ByteArray {
    val inputStream = FileInputStream(File(videoPath))
    val buffer = ByteArrayOutputStream()

    var nRead: Int
    val byteData = ByteArray(16384)

    while (inputStream.read(byteData, 0, byteData.size).also { nRead = it } != -1) {
        buffer.write(byteData, 0, nRead)
    }
    return buffer.toByteArray()
}
```

The way I obtain my video's is through either one of the following two intents:

```
private fun selectMultipleVideos() {
    globalContext.checkPersmissions(Arrays.asList(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){ response ->
        if(response){
            showCameraChoiceDialog(options, DialogInterface.OnClickListener{ dialog, which ->
                when(which){
                    0 -> {
                        val takeVideoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
                        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO)
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
                        intent.setType("video/mp4")
                        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEOS)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

My onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO) {
            val videoUri = data!!.data
            val filePath = getPath(globalContext, videoUri!!)
            amountOfVideosUploaded++
            val videoBytes = FileInputStream(File(filePath)).use { input -> input.readBytes() }
            videoByteArray.add(LocalFile(filePath, videoBytes))
            if (contentReminder.num_required_videos != amountOfVideosUploaded) {
                if (localVideoArray.size != contentReminder.num_required_videos) {
                    localVideoArray.add("")
                }
                localVideoArray[amountOfVideosUploaded] = filePath
            } else {
                localVideoArray[0] = filePath
            }

            setupList()
            videosDelivered.text = DataStorage.generalData.translations?.app__contentinbox__submit_video_label + " (" + amountOfVideosUploaded + "/" + contentReminder.num_required_videos + ")"
        } else {
            selectedVideos = getSelectedVideos(requestCode, data!!)
            selectedVideo = getSelectedVideo(requestCode, data)
            amountOfVideosUploaded++
            val videoPath = getVideoPathFromURI(getSelectedVideoUri(requestCode, data))
            val videoBytes = FileInputStream(File(videoPath)).use { input -> input.readBytes() }
            videoByteArray.add(LocalFile(selectedVideo, videoBytes))
            if (contentReminder.num_required_videos != amountOfVideosUploaded) {
                if (localVideoArray.size != contentReminder.num_required_videos) {
                    localVideoArray.add("")
                }
                localVideoArray[amountOfVideosUploaded] = selectedVideos[i]
            } else {
                localVideoArray[0] = selectedVideos[i]
            }

            setupList()
            videosDelivered.text = DataStorage.generalData.translations?.app__contentinbox__submit_video_label + " (" + amountOfVideosUploaded + "/" + contentReminder.num_required_videos + ")"
        }
    }
}
```

Some of my helper methods:

```
private fun getSelectedVideoUri(requestCode: Int, data: Intent): Uri {
    return data.data!!
}

private fun getSelectedVideo(requestCode: Int, data:Intent): String {
    var result : String = ""
    val videoURI = data.data!!
    val filePath = getPath(globalContext, videoURI)
    result = filePath
    return result
}

private fun getSelectedVideos(requestCode: Int, data:Intent): MutableList<String> {
    val result : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    val videoURI = data.data!!
    val filePath = getPath(globalContext, videoURI)
    result.add(filePath)
    return result
}
```

If it does NOT get an error I upload it to the server with the following method:

```
fun uploadVideoFiles(module: String, file: LocalFile, completionHandler: (path: String) -> Unit){
    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
    params["module"] = module
    params["action"] = "uploadFiles"

    val request = object : MultipartRequest(Method.POST, Router.getUploadUrl(), Response.Listener { response ->
        try {
            completionHandler(Gson().fromJson(String(response.data), FileResponse::class.java).data.file_path)
        } catch (ignore: Exception){
            showSnackbar("Er is iets fout gegaan", ERROR)
        }})
    {
        override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            return params
        }

        override fun getByteData(): MutableMap<String, DataPart> {
            val attachment = HashMap<String, DataPart>()
            val extension = ".mp4"
            attachment["files"] = DataPart(generateCustomString() + extension, file.byteArray!!, MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.replace(".", ""))!!)
            return attachment
        }
    }

    request.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(600000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
    volleyHelper.addToRequestQueue(request)
}
```

Now the error I get (for each of the methods shown + my own / and all the other methods I tried):

```
2021-08-13 11:57:19.726 31911-31911/nl.mycontent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: nl.mycontent, PID: 31911
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 268435472 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 124MB until OOM, target footprint 163389616, growth limit 268435456
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3161)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at nl.mycontent.controller.video.VideoDetail.readAllBytes(VideoDetail.kt:199)
    at nl.mycontent.controller.video.VideoDetail.onActivityResult(VideoDetail.kt:169)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8300)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5353)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5401)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Now I'm hoping there is anyone who can tell me for all Android Versions (since each version has different access requirements for external storage and stuff nowadays) how I can read a file without getting the OOM exception but also most importantly WHY the solution works and WHERE it went wrong on my end.

Comment: `val videoPath = getVideoPathFromURI(getSelectedVideoUri(requestCode, data))` If you have a nice uri then you dont need a file path to put the bytes of the file in a byte array. You can open an inputstream for the uri and then read the bytes. No fuss. Much less code.

Comment: But what is the reason that you want to put a big file completely in memory? I see no reason doing so.

Comment: To be honest all I need is to make sure the file gets uploaded to the server correctly but since uploading video's/photo's sometimes is really annoying with android I might have gotten a bit lost in the process and it might just be that I am doing stuff I don't even need to do. But since I don't have the knowledge to understand everything that's happening under the hood with stuff like this I couldn't figure out what I could skip/drop or should do instead. Will try your uri solution first now =)

Comment: That already is a good idea. But with inputstreamrequestbody you do not need that byte array at all.

Comment: I will look into that first then. It's funny I saw your name at almost every other question which was similar to mine on Stackoverflow. Thanks now already for helping me think in a direction because sometimes I get so completely lost when programming!

Comment: Here is a good  link: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html

Comment: Is there any other way to get a bytearray from the file? Because at the line: videoByteArray.add(LocalFile(selectedVideo, videoBytes) I give videoBytes (which is Bytearray) as parameter. So I think all I need is to be able to get a bytearray even though the file is really large, your answers seem a bit of a hassle compared to what I need. Do you agree? Again, I might misunderstand completely what needs to happen but it feels like that's the only problem I have since the uploading itself is not the problem since we have a default MultipartRequest in our library.

Comment: No. I do not agree. Putting a big file in a byte array in order to upload the file is a bad approach and leads to trouble as you have seen. But if you have a library that works you are done. `Is there any other way to get a bytearray from the file?` The way you fill the array does not matter. The array becomes too big for every way. That is the problem.

Comment: The model for LocalFile is as follows, class LocalFile(
    var fileName: String = "",
    var byteArray: ByteArray? = null
), so it might be better to find a completely different solution to upload the video's? Because based on what I have right now it really needs the bytearray as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only trying to upload the video files, why not use a custom `RequestBody` which means you're not reading the entire file into memory? Like so:

```kotlin
class InputStreamRequestBody(
    private val contentResolver: ContentResolver,
    private val uri: Uri) : RequestBody()
{
    override fun contentType(): MediaType? {
        val contentType = contentResolver.getType(uri)
        return contentType?.toMediaTypeOrNull()
    }

    override fun writeTo(sink : BufferedSink)
    {
        val input = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        input?.use { sink.writeAll(it.source()) }
            ?: throw IOException("Could not open URI")
    }
}
```

Then in `onActivityResult()`:

```kotlin
val reqBody = InputStreamRequestBody(requireContext().contentResolver, videoFileUri)
viewModel.uploadVideo(reqBody)
```

Then, depending on design pattern, upload your video in lets say a `ViewModel`:

```kotlin
fun uploadVideo(video: RequestBody) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + someExceptionHandler) {
        val videoRequestBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", "some_video", video)
        val response = someRetrofitService.uploadVideo(videoRequestBody)
    }
}
```

Where the `Retrofit` service method looks something like this:

```kotlin
@Multipart
@POST("api/v1/files/videos") suspend fun uploadVideo(
    @Part video: MultipartBody.Part? = null)
```

Comment: Bit late but this works! But eventually one of my co-workers told me to just set the max size to 100 MB because of the server. Anyway I really appreciate your answer! =)